Is there any way to control placement of block descriptions in mermaid block-beta?
The following mermaid code will create the block digram shown above.
block-beta
  columns 3
  block:outer["want label visible"]:3
    l["left"]
    m("middle")
    r["right"]
  end    

How can I control the position for the label of the "outer" block so that it aligns to the top of the "outer" block instead of being centered and therefore hidden under the left, middle, and right blocks?

I had the same problem and came up with this workaround:
block-beta
  block:outer["want label visible\n\n\n"]
    columns 3
    space:3
    l["left"]
    m("middle")
    r["right"]
  end 


Thank you!  That does what I needed.  Would be nice to have a little more fine control, but works.

An alternative is to use CSS to style the parent block.
block-beta
  block:outer["want label visible"]
    l["left"]
    m("middle")
    r["right"]
    style outer color:red;padding-bottom:3em
  end 


See on Mermaid Live Editor
